# Let's encrypt doesn't SSL all pages

Tags: iis, lets-encrypt

why Let's encrypt with latest Win ecma doesn't secure all of mine pages?

https://jepsano.net/ is secured, pages under main also https://jepsano.net/2020/05/10/cernobylska-havarie-prepis-od-martina-roty-z-vedeckeho-kladiva/ but older pages not: https://jepsano.net/2014/03/28/moje-prvni-cwg/

Thanks for explanation

Comment: Read the warnings from your web browser to learn what mistakes you make in the web pages. Mixing HTTP and HTTPS contents together is obviously not secure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mixing http and https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853740/mixing-http-and-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use F12 to open the developer tool, you will see this:
[image]

So please change these image's source link to https instead of http.